# Running Jspresso Human Resources sample application

Tags: java, jspresso

I have downloaded Jspresso Human Resource sample appplication from here:

http://www.jspresso.org/page/jspresso-download-area

I don't know about Jspresso framework. I just want to run this downloaded Human Resource Sample application and see how it works. But from the downloaded content I don't know how to make it run. It would be nice if I can run it from command prompt because later I want to profile the application with Java profiler (the profiler I use is command line tool). I already have JDK and Tomcat installed.

Does somebody know how to run this Human Resource sample application from Jspresso?

Comment: No not yet. I am trying to nstall it in Ubuntu 12.04. Could you suggest some good and simple way to install it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to install and make it run here:

http://www.jspresso.org/page/jspresso-10-minutes